# Your Ruby version is 2.2.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.6, except my Gemfile specifies 2.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, gemfile, gemfile.lock

*I've looked all over SO; if I missed a dupe question I'm sorry*

I'm trying to deploy a rails app using capistrano. It's giving me the error "Your Ruby version is 2.2.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.6"

Yes, this *was* true at one point, but I've since edited my gemfile to use 2.2.5, nowhere in the gemfile.lock is there a reference to 2.2.6, but it's still giving me the exact same error.

Comment: remove gemfile.lock; run bundle install; add gemfile.lock and commit; will work

Comment: @VKatz thank you but I tried this and got the same result

Comment: Can you include the gemfile in the question?

Comment: Have you specified ruby `2.2.6` at the top of your Gemfile by any chance?

Comment: Is problem has been solved or still have same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

After update your gem file you must run

```
bundle install
```

Of course, this ruby version should be install in your machine.